# Probability question about putting X items in K things

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, combinations

> The question is: "8 employees want to book meetings with their manager on randomly chosen days of the work week, from Monday till Friday. What's the probability that the manager has at least one day without a booking?"

I've tried it in two ways but it hasn't worked:

1. I said that the probability of an employee booking a specific day is $1/5$, so the probability of all $8$ booking on any day except one is $(4/5)^8$. Then, I multiplied that by $5$ to accomodate for all days, but didn't work.
2. I said the total number of ways of employees booking a meeting is $(8+5-1)C(5-1)$, which is $495$. Then, I said the number of ways employees can book where there's at least one meeting a day is $(3+5-1)C(5-1)$, which is $35$. Then, I said $35/495$ is the probability that there's at least one meeting every day, so the probability that there's at least one day off should be that subtracted from $1$, and it didn't work either.

Comment: This is related to Stirling's numbers of the second kind, which is not easy to calculate exactly, but easy to approximate for large $X$.

Comment: The first method is a step in the right direction, but you're double-counting.  If no one books on Monday or Tuesday, you count that twice.  Google inclusion and exclusion.  The second way is just wrong, because not all the $495$ ways are equiprobable.

Comment: @saulspatz So, does that mean I need to account for each specific set where there's at least one empty day? IE, (4/5)^8 + (3/5)^8 + (2/5)^8 + (1/5)^8

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is the set of all permutations where manager has at least one day free from one to one meetings with employees, then by principle of inclusion-exclusion,

$|A| = \displaystyle {5 \choose 4}4^8 - {5 \choose 3}3^8 + {5 \choose 2}2^8 - {5 \choose 1} = 264625$

You can alternatively compute this by using Stirling Number of the second kind,

$|A| = 5^8 - 5! \ S2[8,5] = 264625$.

$S2[8,5]$ returns number of permutations where manager has meetings all $5$ days without any distinction between days. Multiplying by $5!$ makes days distinct. We then subtract it from unrestricted permutations $5^8$ and that gives us all permutations where manager has at least one of the days free.

Comment: Just a question about the inclusion/exclusion principle in general, but would you be able to tell me why do the signs alternate between each one?

Comment: The first term is ${5 \choose 4} 4^8$. This has overcounted permutations where manager had meetings only $3$ days. Take an example - Say you choose Tue to Fri and Monday is free. Now $4^8$ will count permutations where Tuesday is free along with Monday being free. Now when we move to Tuesday being free, we again have permutations where Monday and Tuesday are both free. Do you see the overcounting? Now when we subtract, permutations where meetings were over $2$ days get undercounted...

Comment: Ahh alright, I think I get it. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using Inclusion/Exclusion, the solution is

$$\dbinom{5}{4}\left(\dfrac{4}{5}\right)^8-\dbinom{5}{3}\left(\dfrac{3}{5}\right)^8+\dbinom{5}{2}\left(\dfrac{2}{5}\right)^8-\dbinom{5}{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^8 = \dfrac{2117}{3125} = 0.67744$$

Comment: This answer is right, but I have a question. Why do the signs between each alternate? I don't understand why the 1st and third one are positive, while the 2nd and 4th one are negative?

Comment: @Nightwing As saulspatz suggested, google Inclusion/Exclusion. The topic is a bit too large to include as a comment or even as an answer here. It is not that it is a difficult concept, it is just that it takes a lot of words to describe. It is far shorter to write it mathematically than explain what the math is actually doing.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that. Thank you so much for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to set up a recursion: the probability the manager has $d$ days booked is by $n$ employees satisfies $$p_n(d) = \tfrac{d}{5}p_{n-1}(d) + \tfrac{5-(d-1)}{5}p_{n-1}(d-1)$$ starting at $p_0(0)=1$. You get a table like this

```
    d   0    1           2           3           4          5
n                       
0       1   0           0           0           0           0
1       0   1           0           0           0           0
2       0   0.2         0.8         0           0           0
3       0   0.04        0.48        0.48        0           0
4       0   0.008       0.224       0.576       0.192       0
5       0   0.0016      0.0960      0.4800      0.3840      0.0384
6       0   0.00032     0.03968     0.34560     0.49920     0.11520
7       0   0.000064    0.016128    0.231168    0.537600    0.215040
8       0   0.0000128   0.0065024   0.1483776   0.5225472   0.3225600
```

and you want $1-p_8(5) = 0.67764 = \frac{2117}{3125}=\frac{264625}{5^8}$ where $5^8$ is the total number of ways the meetings could be booked